# Как прокрутить массив заданное кол-во раз по часовой допустим?

Tags: php, массивы

напр. имеем 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 а на выходе получим 5 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 0, прокрутить один раз не сложно, а вот как заданное кол-во раз? Вот что у меня пока получилось, к сожалению результат не удовлетворительный, что работает не так?

```
$arr = [ 0, 1 , 2 , 3, 4 , 5 ];

$pop = array_pop($arr);
$arr = array_start_push($arr,$pop);

var_dump($arr);
// array(6) { [0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(0) [2]=> int(1) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(3) [5]=> int(4) }

function array_start_push($array, $element){
return array_merge(array($element), $array);
}

function cycle( array $arr_in, $steps ){

    for ($st = 0; $st <= $steps; $st++) {

        $pop = array_pop($arr_in);
        $arr_in = array_start_push($arr_in,$pop);

    }

    return $arr_in;

}

$cycled = cycle($arr,1);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($cycled);
/* array(6) {
  [0]=>
  int(3)
  [1]=>
  int(4)
  [2]=>
  int(5)
  [3]=>
  int(0)
  [4]=>
  int(1)
  [5]=>
  int(2)
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

написал свой код, все работает

```
$inputarray=array (0,1,2,3,4,5);

function krutimarray($array,$step)
{
    $real_step=fmod($step, count($array));

    if ($real_step!=0)
    {
       $left_array=array_slice($array, 0,count($array)-$real_step);
       $right_array=array_slice($array,count($array)-$real_step,$real_step);
       return array_merge($right_array,$left_array);
    }
    else 
    {
        return $array;
    }
}

$out_array=krutimarray($inputarray, 8);
```

Comment: все отлично работает!

Comment: `1C + php = krutimarray` :DDD

Answer (score 1):

?! 
Так если в строчке for ($st = 0; $st <= $steps; $st++)  убрать равно 
for ($st = 0; $st < $steps; $st++) то тоже все работает))

```
function cycle( array $arr_in, $steps ) {
    for ($st = 0; $st < $steps; $st++) {
        $pop = array_pop($arr_in);
        $arr_in = array_merge(array($pop), $arr_in);
    }
    return $arr_in;
}

$arr = array( 0, 1 , 2 , 3, 4 , 5 );
$cycled = cycle($arr,8);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($cycled);
```

Comment: а представте массив из 500 элементов, и задать прокрутить его 1001 раз- сколько будет работать ваш код? сколько ненужных операций будет произведено?

Comment: Ну изначально вопрос стоял как "что работает не так?" 
Я и написал что "=" лишнее, а вообще, зачем либо "Прокручивать" массив не лучшая идея в любой реализации, IMHO..

Answer (score 1):

Вот **отличная** [статья](http://codelab.ru/task/cycle_shift/) с подробным описанием трех нетривиальных быстрых алгоритмов циклического сдвига массива "на месте".